# Single verb to hold something high

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a specific verb that means "to hold something high in the air", such as a flag or a sign?

Comment: Do you want a verb that means "to start to hold something in the air" or "to be in a state of holding something in the air"?

Comment: Do you want a verb that means "to hold something high in one's hands"?

Comment: I would say 'grasp' but then again your definition is sounds more like fly

Comment: I mean to be in the state of holding something, not the start of it.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for ***hoist*** or ***elevate***

We usually **hoist** a flag.

**Elevate** something to a higher position.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, [***fly***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flew+the+flag%2Cflew+the+banner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflew%20the%20flag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflew%20the%20banner%3B%2Cc0).

> : to hoist aloft, as for display, signaling, etc.: 
>   *to fly a flag*. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fly)